# It is possible to do something like XE2 LiveBindings in D2010?

Tags: delphi, livebindings

It's factible or it uses some compiler technology only available in XE2 ?

I just want to bind (bidirectional) a TEdit.Text property to a object function that returns a string in code (I don't need designer components or expression evaluators)..

Thanks!

Comment: Check this article of Stefan Glienke  http://delphisorcery.blogspot.com/2011/04/data-bindings-revisited.html you can download the sample and the binding library from here http://delphisorcery.googlecode.com/files/DataBindingSample.zip

Comment: I recommend to use the latest revision from the svn since the zip archives are very old and outdated. There is also currently a problem in Delphi 2010 which is related to some in XE fixed bug in the Rtti.pas which causes an EInvalidCast exception but I am working on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess you could try [Delphi sorcery library](http://code.google.com/p/delphisorcery/). It has quite powerful data binding solution  which should work in all the modern Delphi versions.

Answer (score 2):

No, as far as I can tell, the LiveBindings system was implemented entirely in code with no new language features introduced to support it.  Which is a bit of a shame, IMO; it could be a much simpler and overall better system if the language had support for something like [property references.](http://delphisorcery.blogspot.com/2011/07/property-references-in-delphi-possible.html)